# How to underline a Roman numeral in an ordered HTML list

Tags: html, css

I am working on front end project and there is a requirement for ordered list that display some headings. But my client need to display underline that cover roman number of style type  and title in `<li>`
this is my html code for that page :

```html
<ol type="I">
  <li><span>Non-Canadian Investors</span>// this is my heading that needs to be underline with roman number also
    <p>Cce or information to anyone </p>
  </li>
</ol>
```

I need to display some text in li block as well that's why I use `<p>` tag and `<span>` tag for underline purpose

Answer (score 1):

If you want to underline also the text then just add text-decoration: underline; rule to .custom-counter li 
You can achieve the desired result like this:

```css
.custom-counter {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.custom-counter li {
  counter-increment: step-counter;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.custom-counter li::before {
  content: counter(step-counter, upper-roman);
  text-decoration: underline;
  padding: 3px 8px;
}
```

```html
<ol class="custom-counter">
  <li><span>Non-Canadian Investors</span>// this is my heading that needs to be underline with roman number also
    <p>Cce or information to anyone </p>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```css
ol{
  list-style-position: inside;
}
li{
  position: relative;
}
.underlined{
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  margin: 0px;
}
.underlined span{
  padding-left: 25px;
}
.text{
  padding-left: 25px;
}
```

```html
<ol type="I">
    <li>
        <p class="underlined"><span>some underlined text</span></p>
        <p class="text">some text</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <p class="underlined"><span>some underlined text</span></p>
        <p class="text">some text</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <p class="underlined"><span>some underlined text</span></p>
        <p class="text">some text</p>
    </li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

you may use

```css
.list {
  counter-reset: my-badass-counter;
}
.list dt{
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
.list dt:before {
  content: counter(my-badass-counter, lower-roman);
  counter-increment: my-badass-counter;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<dl class="list">

 <dt>list head 1</dt>
 <dd>list data 1</dd>
 
 <dt>list head 2</dt>
 <dd>list data 2</dd>
 
 <dt>list head 3</dt>
 <dd>list data 3</dd>

</dl>
```

Answer (score 0):

A dirty trick is to use CSS counters, and then absolutely position the counters (placed within a ``` ::before`` pseudo-element). To force the underline to extend towards the text, you will have to insert an arbitrary amount of whitespace, in this case I use the em space, represented as ```\2003` in unicode.

This trick works in the sense that **it supports multiline content**, see the proof-of-concept example below. Also, I have chosen to use a different color for the counter text just so show the visuals:

```css
ol {
  counter-reset: listCounter;
  list-style: none;
}
ol li {
  padding-left: 2rem; /* Some arbitrary spacing */
  position: relative;
}
ol li::before {
  color: #ff0000;
  counter-increment: listCounter;
  content: counter(listCounter, upper-roman) "\2003\2003\2003"; 
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: underline;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  max-width: 2rem;    /* Must match the left padding above */
  overflow: hidden;   /* Hide overflowing underline */
}
ol li span {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<ol type="I">
  <li><span>Non-Canadian Investors</span>
    <p>Cce or information to anyone </p>
  </li>
  <li><span>This is a very long title This is a very long title This is a very long title This is a very long title This is a very long title This is a very long title</span>
    <p>Cce or information to anyone </p>
  </li>
</ol>
```